# SSE, постоянно попадает в метод ошибки

Tags: php, javascript

Использую вот такую библиотеку для SSE запросов:
https://github.com/Yaffle/EventSource/

Сервер:

```
    header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
    header('Cache-Control: no-cache'); // recommended to prevent caching of event data.
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

    ...

    //echo ":" . str_repeat(" ", 2048) . "\n"; // 2 kB padding for IE
    echo "retry: 2000\n";
    echo "id: {$lastEventId}" . PHP_EOL;
    echo "data: " . ProcessingData::load()->getJson($updateProposals) . PHP_EOL;
    echo PHP_EOL;

    sleep(2);

    ob_flush();
    flush();
```

Клиент:

```
var listener = function (event) {
                var type = event.type;

                console.log(type + ": " + (type === "message" ? event.data : es.url));

              };

              es.addEventListener("open", listener);
              es.addEventListener("message", listener);
              es.addEventListener("error", listener);
```

Проблема в том, что всегда попадаем в **es.addEventListener("error", listener);**

Пример:
Посылаю запрос на верный урл, данные с сервера приходят, попадаем в message, все хорошо, но и непонятно почему в error тоже попадаем 
Посылаю запрос на не верный url, приходит 404 ошибка, в message не попадаем, в error попадаем.

Подскажите пожалуйста почему я постоянно попадаю в error ?

Comment: Может из-за одинаковых listener ?

Comment: а не важно, пробовал разными вариантами. 

Говорят дохнет процесс пхп и из-за этого ошибка.